# change value of a char array in a function

Tags: arrays, c, pointers

I try to change a value of a char inside a function, but it doesn't work, I can't change the main function and the function call

```
typedef char* char_array;

int change(char_array arr, int index, char c){

    int length = 6;
    char *new_array = calloc(length, sizeof(char_array));
    new_array = arr;
    str = calloc(length, sizeof(char_array));

    if(index >= 0 && index <= length){
        for(int i = 0; i < length; i++){
            if(i == index){
                arr[i] = c;
            }else{
                arr[i] = new_array[i];
            }
            
        }
        return 0;
    }else{
        return -1;
    }
}
int main(){
    char_array arr = "Hello!";
    change(arr, 5, ' ');
    printf("%s", arr);
```

}

correct print: Hello
but print: Hello!

Comment: `arr` points to a literal string. These are not modifiable. Use `char arr[] = "Hello!";`

Comment: Where is str declared? In any case, str is completely local the change function and doesn't exist after the the call. Review how pointers work, what does 'arr' point to?

Comment: @Cebolexx Where is there the identifier astr declared?

Comment: @Cebolexx If to update the typo then this code snippet     char *new_array = calloc(length, sizeof(astr));
    new_array = str; produces a memory leak.